# problem with TreeListNode

Tags: devexpress

I'm trying to create a treelistnode. The following below code getting an error:

```
        private TreeListNode CreateTreeNode(EntityInfo entity)
        {
             CategoryInfo info = entity as CategoryInfo;

             TreeListNode treeNode = new TreeListNode();
             treeNode.SetValue("CatName", info.CatName);
             treeNode.SetValue("CateCode", info.CateCode);
             treeNode.SetValue("Id", info.Id);
             treeNode.Tag = info.Id;

             return treeNode;
         }
```

Error

```
DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNode.TreeListNode(int, DevExpress.XtraTreeList.Nodes.TreeListNodes)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

I need your help to create a separate treelistnode 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TreeList's [AppendNode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_AppendNodetopic) method instead.  Please also refer to the [How to: Create Nodes in Unbound Mode in Code](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5559) topic.